# Putting Unusual Fonts into Web Pages

Tags: fonts

On a web project for a client, we want to use a type of "script" font that looks like handwriting in a few places throughout the site.  The problem is that these are not typically system fonts and so we don't think we can advise the client to use them (client likes the look); they may or may not render nicely at the client.

We are planning to go forward by just creating GIF's of various phrases using the font locally, then using those images on the site pages.  This seems to me to be a little kludgy (though it should work).  Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about) uses javascript to replace headings and such with text rendered in a SVG or VML.  It fails nicely, that is the headings are not replaced if the SVG or VML cannot be rendered.

[typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) is similar, using the canvas tag.

Although there are always the issues with font licensing.

Comment: Using a link I found to a great evaluation blog post at http://thatguynamedandy.com/blog/text-replacement-comparison, I think CuFon sounds the best for my needs.  I will give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at **sIFR** ? 
http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/

It uses JavaScript to replace HTML-tags with a flash-movie that has the special font embedded.

**Also...**

The comparison between the different methods has been discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692990/sifr-vs-cufon-vs-typeface-js

Comment: The link is good.  Here is an even better one I picked up in that thread you provided: http://thatguynamedandy.com/blog/text-replacement-comparison

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the desired font is on Google Web Fonts and then reference it:
http://www.google.com/webfont